# db: b'Drive sharing seems blocked by a firewall'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to integrate postgres Django with docker while i run docker-compose a pop up appears "Docker wants to access drive C", after allowing it I get an error

**db: b'Drive sharing seems blocked by a firewall'**

**settings.py**

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('NAME', 'NRN_temp'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('USER', 'postgres'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('PASSWORD', 'admin'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('HOST', 'localhost')
    }
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  db:
    image: postgres:11.2-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./data/new_db_data_01/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      - nra
```

Tried all the solutions for similar problems but non worked,any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I am running it on windows